# How to use Graph API to get events in my city?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

try to use `search?q=Odessa&type=event` but get answer like

`{
  "data": [
  ]
}`

is this the correct response? And finally, how to get events in my city? Plans to create a web page with a calendar so that you can see the events in the city for a specific day. Graph API allows you to get the time, address, and cover of the event, which is very convenient in my case. Or maybe there are other ways to complete the task?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyIUZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get events by city. You can only get places by location, and events for those places. But that would be separate calls.

With batch request, those calls can be combined:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/#operations

Be aware that it would only be faster with batch requests, but it will count as the same amount of API calls for limits.

Comment: exactly as i mentioned, i assume. hard do say what that site does exactly, as it´s not in english. but i see no "search for events in city xy" funtionality. how they get their events, you would have to ask them directly. it´s also possible that they scrape facebook, which is not allowed.